# Spring Cloud Data Flow + SqlServer + Tables creation

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

SCDF project creates tables/sequences on the fly while starting the application. but our database is in shared environment, it doesn't have any create table permission. Is it possible to create tables/indices/sequences well before that are needed for Spring Cloud Data Flow project to run ?. if you have any SQL scripts, please provide me the link ?..

Answer (score 1):

The SCDF and Skipper rely on Flyway for database schema migration between the releases. It is a strict requirement, so, unfortunately, there's no way around it right now.

You could work around this situation by letting Flyway create all the required schemas automatically in either dev/staging like environments and then manually you could export the schema/data using the approved database tooling to the other environments that have restricted access.

Once when the tables/data exists, Flyway wouldn't interfere or reattempt to create the schemas when SCDF bootstraps. I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Sabby, As you mentioned we were able to create these tables in other lower environments, but when we moved these tables pre-prod environments and start SCDF app, we get this below error....org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException: Error while executing beforeBaseline callback: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [CREATE TABLE TASK_LOCK (
  LOCK_KEY CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
  REGION VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  CLIENT_ID CHAR(36),
  CREATED_DATE DATETIME NOT NULL,
  constraint LOCK_PK primary key (LOCK_KEY, REGION)
)There is already an object named 'TASK_LOCK' in the database.;

Comment: not sure if this comment still helps - but "task_lock" is a table generated when the SCDF task runs - it will NOT be created at SCDF start time. We might be able to skip it when we first bootstrap the DB.